# MPI dynamic communication between 2 Processes

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi

I have a process that manages a list of 2d arrays and passes different 2d arrays to each process. There is a possibility that I have not enough processes for all 2d arrays So I need to ask process 0 which manages the list of 2d arrays if there are any arrays left after any process which is not 0 finishes working with the first received array. I dont know how to implement this.

```
(...)
if(rank == 0)
        //check if we have elements in 2d array left
        while (ptr != NULL)
        {
            MPI_Status status;
            int sig;
            // Wait for a process to ask for a 2d array
            MPI_Recv(&sig, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_ANY_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            // send it to them
            MPI_Send(&ptr->grid.sudoku, N * N, MPI_INT, status.MPI_SOURCE, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            ptr = ptr->next;
        }
        // free memory
        delete_grids(list);
        elementsAvailable = 0;
    }
    // rank != 0
    else
    {
        lookForSolution(recvGrid(), rank); // recvGrid calls MPI_Recv and passes 
//the given array to a function to calculate something
    }

    MPI_Bcast(&sudokusAvailable, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD); // Here I thought I make a MPI_Bcast 
//to tell other processes that process 0 has no arrays left but If I put it here 
//the next if statement will never be called in the first place

    if (rank != 0 && elementsAvailable == 1)
    {
        MPI_Status status;
        // Send process 0 that ready for new 2d array
        MPI_Send(1, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        lookForSolution(recvGrid(), rank);
    }
(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to let process zero send data to another process, and then post an `MPI_Irecv` for the result. When all the processes have work, the manager does an `MPI_Waitany` to see if any process is returning results, if so, accept, and send new work. If the manager runs out of work, it sends a special message to the workers, and they quit.

From here on it's an exercise to the reader.

If you want the manager also to participate in the work, it becomes a little more complicated, and you could solve the whole thing with one-sided communication, creating in effect a shared object with all the work.

Comment: Sounds like its not very performance efficient if process 0 has no more work left and has to tell every single process that it has none so it can quit. But i dont see how I could implement a broadcast here instead.

Comment: Don't make statements about performance unless you can actually measure it. And consider: you are already doing a whole bunch of sends to each worker process. How wasteful will it be to have one extra send? But if you want to optimize that, try a non-blocking barrier.